# How to code and run lines while training a model on VS Code remote server connection?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, deep-learning, remote-server, vscode-remote

while I'm training a model and the interpreter busy, is there a way that I can run another file on a new window or something.

[I'm training a model here and the interpreter is busy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0P55f.png)

I want to code and test things on the commandline/python interpreter while the server is busy training my model.

Thanks,
Chung

Additional img:
[Trying to run 'import time' from the editor as training the model and the command is queued to the already-busy terminal instead of the split one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZdlc.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you take the `Shift+Enter` shortcut to execute the `Run Selection/Line in Terminal` command.

The VSCode will create a Terminal named `Python` to execute all the commands from `Run Selection/Line in Terminal` command.

If you want to avoid it. You need to create a new terminal and execute the python file manually instead of the shortcut command.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can simply open a new terminal by clicking the `+` sign on the top right-hand corner of the terminal panel. This will open another terminal that you can use to run commands.

If you would like to have them side by side, you may click the `split terminal` sign next to the `+` sign to open another terminal next to the current running terminal too.

More on that in the VSC guide [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal)

Comment: Hi, I tried that but when I try to 'shift + enter' the code on the editor, it tries to run it on the terminal that is already training the model, so the line doesn't run until the training is done. In the screenshot that I have added, I am trying to run 'import time' as training the model and it doesn't work even after I split the terminal.